# Query a sqlite3 database and send query over raw socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, sqlite

I have the socket connected and working just fine but I'm new to sqlite3 and not sure how to query the database and then send the results of the query over the socket connection. This is what I have and I am sure it will work when the query is properly put into the socket. Thanks!

```
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(raw_sock, server_side=True)
ssl_sock.sendall('Here comes my database.'.encode('ascii'))
connection = sqlite3.connect("Clients")
clients = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM clients")
read = clients.readline()
ssl_sock.sendall(read)
ssl_sock.close()


  File "database_server.py", line 48, in <module>
server(args.host, args.port, args.s, args.a)
```

File "database_server.py", line 34, in server
    read = clients.read()
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Obviously I can't just read but what is the proper way to send a sqlite3.Cursor over a socket?

Comment: dont use sqlite for this ... or switch to providing a restful api ... basically this seems totally wrong and very hacky

Comment: to further note and more to direct some hints if you really want to do this
`for result in cursor.fetchall(): ssl_sock.sendall(json.dumps(result))`

Comment: I'm having some trouble using the bulk sql packages on my el capitan OS X for example mysql is not compatible or I would gladly be doing so. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: posgresql ... but you will have to read about how to expose it to an outside port ...

Comment: Thanks I will certainly do that.